# How to remove a set of files using a given string containing a wildcarded path in bash/zsh?

Tags: macos, zsh, glob, oh-my-zsh

**Assumption**: Let's say I have a wildcarded string variable, which represents a path to a set of files ending with .txt (containing spaces):

```
a="/hello world/*.txt"
```

**Problem**: I want to remove these files in terminal using $rm$:

```
rm $a
```

When I execute the above command, I get the following error:

```
rm: /hello world/*.txt: No such file or directory
```

Same for below:

```
rm "$a"
```

Or even if I escape the spaces, I still get the same error.

**Question:** How can I remove these paths in bash based on a given wildcard path in a variable format.

**More info:**

- Output of `$- == 569JNRXZghiklms`
- OS: Mac OS X 10.15.7
- I'm using zsh
- Output of my bash --version: `❯ bash --version GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19) Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: Add output of `echo $-` to your question (no comment).

Comment: What is the actual name of the file you are looking to remove?

Comment: @RamanSailopal That's not a file. It's a set file endng with .txt

Comment: @Cyrus I updated the question with more info

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a bit different in zsh from other shells (e.g. bash). In most shells, if you expand a variable without putting double-quotes around it (like `rm $a`), then the variable's value is subject to both word splitting (i.e. getting broken up into multiple "words") and also wildcard expansion. In zsh, however, neither word splitting nor wildcard expansion is done to variables even if they're not double-quoted (at least by default).

In your case, you need wildcard expansion to be done, but *not* word splitting (that would break it up into two separate items, "/hello" and "world/*.txt"). In zsh, you can explicitly request that wildcard expansion be done with the `~` prefix:

```
rm ${~a}
```

You could also use `setopt GLOB_SUBST`, which turns wildcard expansion on for all subsequent variable (and command) expansions.

If you were using bash, or some other similar shell, it'd be more complicated, because they don't have natural a way to do wildcard expansion without also doing word splitting. But you can change how the does word splitting, so it doesn't actually do anything:

```
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=
rm $a
IFS=$saveIFS
```

`IFS` is the list of "whitespace" characters that're treated as word separators; when it's the null string, there are no separators, so no actual splitting happens. But you should be sure to set `IFS` back to normal afterward, or you can get weird effects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm looking for a general way of doing this. This is a part of a bigger piece of script and I want to distribute it as a part of a package. Is this `rm ${~a}` a general solution? If not, do you have any suggestions? I wouldn't imagine removing a set of files to be this complicated lol!

Comment: @linker It depends on the bigger picture, but usually the best answer is: don't store glob patterns in variables. Often it makes more sense to store some or all of the fixed parts in variables, and apply the wildcard parts when using them (e.g. `rm "$dir"/*."$ext"`), or expand the wildcard immediately into an array of matching files (e.g. `files=("/hello world"/*.txt)` and then `rm "${files[@]}"`), or a mix of both (e.g. `files=("$dir"/*."$ext")`). If you're scripting in bash, see [BashFAQ #20](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) (though some of it applies to zsh as well).